# Set sshd to serve different shell based on `host`

Tags: bash, ssh, fish

I want my local sshd to serve different shell, based on the `host`.

Example:

- `ssh user@hostname1` -> get's `bash`
- `ssh user@hostname2` -> get's `fish`

Is it possible, and if so, how can it be done?

Comment: Your examples do not match the question. E a.ples have two servers question has just the one

Answer (score 2):

I'm not able to find a way to accomplish what you're asking for directly with `sshd` and the options available in `man sshd_config` or `man sshd`.

#### Method #1 via ssh client

The first method that comes to mind is pretty straightforward. You can either do it directly with just `ssh`.

```
$ ssh -t user@someserver bash
```

-or-

```
$ ssh -t user@someserver dash
```

#### Examples

*bash*

```
$ ssh -t manny.bub.lan -l manny bash
$ ps | grep $$
31691 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
```

*dash*

```
$ ssh -t manny.bub.lan -l manny dash
$ ps | grep $$
31730 pts/0    00:00:00 dash
```

*csh*

```
$ ssh -t manny.bub.lan -l manny csh
manny:~% ps | grep $$
 1687 pts/0    00:00:00 csh
```

*fish*

```
$ ssh -t manny.bub.lan -l manny fish
Welcome to fish, the friendly interactive shell
manny@manny ~> ps | grep $$_
fish: $$ is not the pid. In fish, please use %self.
ps | grep $$
           ^
manny@manny ~> ps | grep %self
 4218 pts/0    00:00:00 fish
```

#### Method #2 via alias

You could leverage the above method in #1, and build aliases like these:

```
$ alias sshmanny1="ssh -t manny@manny-rei210-2.bub.lan bash"
$ alias sshmanny1="ssh -t manny@manny-rei210-2.bub.lan fish"
```

Then use them like so:

```
$ sshmanny1
manny@manny:~$ exit
exit
Shared connection to manny.bub.lan closed.


$ sshmanny2
Welcome to fish, the friendly interactive shell
manny@manny ~> exit
Shared connection to manny.bub.lan closed.
```

#### Method #3 ~/.ssh/config

The third method I was able to find would build configurations that can do this on the client side of your SSH connection, instead of on the server via SSHD.

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/config
Host manny1
    HostName manny.bub.lan
    RemoteCommand bash
    RequestTTY force
    User manny

Host manny2
    HostName manny.bub.lan
    RemoteCommand fish
    RequestTTY force
    User manny
```

Now when you want to connect you'd do so like this:

```
$ ssh manny1
manny@manny:~$ exit
exit
Shared connection to manny.bub.lan closed.

$ ssh manny2
Welcome to fish, the friendly interactive shell
manny@manny ~> exit
Shared connection to manny.bub.lan closed.
```

#### References

- [Choosing the shell that SSH uses?](https://serverfault.com/questions/106722/choosing-the-shell-that-ssh-uses)